# implement row number ()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

How can I implement `row_number()` window function in sql server without using the function itself, maybe with join on an index table?

or more, how can I implement

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ATLAS_USER_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS RR
```

row number over partition without using this function?

is partition is like group by?

Comment: Why can't you use the function?

Comment: I got this mission during a project of building a database . you have any idea ?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to accomplish, and why isn't `ROW_NUMBER()` adequate?  And yes, `PARTITION BY` is similar in effect to `GROUP BY`.  You can specify `OVER(ORDER BY Event_Time DESC)` if you don't want any grouping at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can add column like

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: sorry confuse it with mysql--->ID int IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: but this will only give me id to each row . row number with partition gives id to each row in each partition

Comment: it is 'like' row num with no partition

Comment: yeah you right , any idea how to do it with partition ?

Comment: i have an idea but it very complicate.lets see maybe you will came with good answer

Comment: hhhh give me a clue , i am on it for days i dont got this task today . i think maybe with a temporary tables ? or index table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Just a try not sure this is exact you are looking for. Note this requires an identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableName
    ([Id] int,[Dates] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #TableName
    ([Id], [Dates])
VALUES

    (1, '2014-08-07 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2014-08-07 00:00:00'),
    (3,  '2014-08-07 00:00:00'),
    (4,  '2014-08-07 00:00:00'),
    (5, '2014-08-08 00:00:00'),
    (6,'2014-08-08 00:00:00'),
    (7, '2014-08-08 00:00:00'),
    (8,  '2014-08-09 00:00:00'),
    (9, '2014-08-09 00:00:00'),
    (10, '2014-08-09 00:00:00'),
    (11, '2014-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (12, '2014-08-10 00:00:00'),
    (13, '2014-08-10 00:00:00')


SELECT CASE
         WHEN [Id]%cn = 0 THEN cn
         ELSE [Id]%cn
       END,
       *
FROM   #TableName a
       JOIN (SELECT Count(1) cn,
                    [Dates]
             FROM   #TableName
             GROUP  BY [Dates]) b
         ON a.[Dates] = b.[Dates]
```

Update :

To add case in where just add the same case statement in where clause.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Id%cn = 0 THEN cn
         ELSE Id%cn
       END,
       *
FROM   atlas_events a
       JOIN (SELECT Count(1) AS cn,
                    Event_Time
             FROM   atlas_events
             GROUP  BY Event_Time) b
         ON a.Event_Time = b.Event_Time
WHERE  PRT_PROJECT_ID = 175
       AND ADV_PROJECT_ID = 713
       AND event_type = 1
       AND CASE
             WHEN [Id]%cn = 0 THEN cn
             ELSE [Id]%cn
           END = 5
```

Comment: @user2783069 That is the count of each group. check the inner query

Comment: its great ! i manage to get to this :  SELECT CASE
         WHEN Id%cn = 0 THEN cn
         ELSE Id%cn
       END,
       *
FROM atlas_events  a 
 JOIN (SELECT Count(1) as cn,
                    Event_Time
             FROM  atlas_events
             GROUP  BY Event_Time) b
         ON a.Event_Time = b.Event_Time
         WHERE PRT_PROJECT_ID = 175 and ADV_PROJECT_ID = 713 and event_type = 1

Comment: how do i only take the "case" columns when equal to 5?

Comment: @user2783069 - which column = 5 ??

Comment: only when this :  CASE
         WHEN [Id]%cn = 0 THEN cn
         ELSE [Id]%cn
       END  eqaul to 5

Comment: what about this one ? 
select EVENT_TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ATLAS_USER_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS RR,
   ATLAS_USER_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_TYPE,ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID 
   from
    ATLAS.ATLAS_EVENTS
     WHERE ADV_PROJECT_ID = 713 and event_type = 1 ) A
      WHERE RR = 3

Comment: @user2783069 - what u want to do with the previous query

Comment: the query you wrote below the update is equal to this ???  select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ATLAS_USER_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS RR,
 ATLAS_USER_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_TYPE,ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID
 from ATLAS_EVENTS
 WHERE PRT_PROJECT_ID = 175 and ADV_PROJECT_ID = 713 and event_type = 1 )
 A WHERE RR = 5

Comment: @user2783069 - yes both are equal

Comment: i am getting more results than then the original query returns in MSSQL i think we have issue in the join condition or something , and offcourse instead of * in the select i put the relevent fileds like the original query

Comment: @user2783069 Without knowing your table structure without having sample data without having expected output its really hard to answer. My answer is  just an idea to your question because there is no enough details on the question!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique identifier in each row, you can get the same functionality using using a correlated subquery or `apply`.  If the event times are distinct:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t2
        where t2.ATLAS_USER_ID = t.ATLAS_USER_ID and
              t2.Event_Time <= t.EventTime
       )
from table t;
```

If they are not distinct, but there is another id in the row:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t2
        where t2.ATLAS_USER_ID = t.ATLAS_USER_ID and
              (t2.Event_Time < t.Event_Time or
               t2.Event_Time = t.Event_Time and t2.id <= t.id
              )
       )
from table t;
```

Comment: t2 and t are the same table ?

Comment: `t2` and `t` are different table aliases.  In this case, they would refer to the same table . . . you would put your table name where `table` is.

Comment: its return the entire table this is the query?look this is the original query ... any idea ?   select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ATLAS_USER_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS RR,
 ATLAS_USER_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_TYPE,ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID,PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID
 from ATLAS.ATLAS_EVENTS
 WHERE PRT_PROJECT_ID = 175 and ADV_PROJECT_ID = 713 and event_type = 1 )
 A WHERE RR = 5

Comment: @user2783069 . . . You added addition filtering to the correlated subquery.  If you want to filter the results, put that in the outer query.